Why add widget to scrollview not working in python kivy
Python file
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem


#Ukuran window
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1000')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

#Set window preview
Window.size = (1000, 600)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("interface.kv")
    
    def test(self):
        for i in range(20):
            item = OneLineListItem(
                text=f'Items number {i}'
            )
            self.root.ids.items.add_widget(item)


MainApp().run()

kivy file
#:kivy 2.3.0

FloatLayout:
#--------------------Header-------------------
    Image:
        source: 'ex.png'
        size_hint: (0.3,0.3)
        pos_hint: {'x':-.05,'y': .75}


    MDLabel:
        text: "Invoice System"
        font_size: '50sp'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'y': .4}

#---------------Item----------------
    MDTextField:
        mode: 'fill'
        hint_text: "???"
        size_hint: (.4, .1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .65}

    MDTextField:
        mode: 'fill'
        hint_text: "???"
        size_hint: (.14, .1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .46, 'y': .65}

    MDTextField:
        mode: 'fill'
        hint_text: "???"
        size_hint: (.14, .1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .61, 'y': .65}

    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
        style: 'filled'
        text: "Add"
        size_hint: (.1, .1)
        pos_hint: {'x': .79, 'y': .65}


#------------ Item List --------------------
    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color: '#B5C0D0'
        size_hint: (.846, .37)
        pos_hint: {'x':.05, 'y': .25}
        padding: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: items



#------------ Last button --------------------
    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
        style: 'filled'
        text: "Make Invoice"
        size_hint: (.21, .15)
        pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .08}

The problem is with the kivy file in the "Item List" section
I tried to create a scroll view inside a container which is a box layout. Inside the box layout, there is a scroll view that contains a list. The list is generated from a "for" loop which produces text to be displayed in the scroll view. However, the scroll view does not display the text generated from the loop.

Do you get an error message?

No, just the text not display in container

I would have expected an error due to the code: self.root.ids.items.add_widget(item) because self.root.ids is a dictionary, and items is a method of the dictionary. So you are trying to call add_widget() on the items() method. Try changing that line to: self.root.ids['items'].add_widget(item).
